# Проблема компиляции приложения Python (содержащего модуль comtypes) через pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Попробовал написать программку на Python 3 и использую его совместно с SAP2000, через API интерфейс(это расчетный МКЭ пакет, не путать просто с SAP). Для доступа из вне, в SAP2000 используется модуль comtypes. Написал тестовый код:

```
import comtypes.client
import os

# get active model
mySapObject = 
comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("CSI.SAP2000.API.SapObject")
SapModel = mySapObject.SapModel

#path to model folder and file
modPath = str(SapModel.GetModelFilepath())
modName = str(SapModel.GetModelFilename())

print(modName)

# get frame list
frameList = SapModel.FrameObj.GetNameList()
frameList = frameList[1]

print(frameList)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модули необходимые для совместной работы SAP2000 и Py установлены и проблем с работой в пределах среды  разработки нет, все работает как надо, все методы, что я тестировал из библиотеки SAP2000 работают и в эксель результаты расчета модели из под среды он мне передавал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее полученный скрипт я пытаюсь компилировать в exe через модуль pyinstaller. Ключи для конвертации использовал следующие:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --windowed --onefile --name=Frame_ReportV02 "D:\\'ПУТЬ К ФАЙЛУ ПИ'\\Frame_ReportV02.py" --paths C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\site-packages
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По окончании конвертации, в командной строке как я думаю критичного ничего нет, т.е. никаких "Ultra Fatal Errors" не отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле ErrorWarnings тоже как я думаю нет ничего критичного. 
Там есть запись о "missing module comtypes.tools...." и т.д. но они 
в работе совместной не участвуют и это скорее всего тоже не критично.

Далее я полученный *.exe копирую в установленную директорию программы и от им. администратора запускаю. При запуске появляется надпись - "Fatal Error".
Причем такая история происходит на всех компах, что я тестировал, там и 
разные наборы модулей и разные среды (Visual Studio, Visual Code, Spyder, IDLE родная питоновская) но FATAL ERROR появляется везде и местоположение exe кстати тоже разное было. Вот скорее всего до этого шага (или еще минус 2) я, что то делаю не так...

Далее я попробовал конвертировать с ключом вместо --windowed использовал
--console т.к. наверняка там хоть чего то нового буд написано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перед этим проверил, что в modules comtypes куда питон все это устанавливает, есть папка gen (она создается в момент первого запуска python для линковки с SAP2000) в которой есть переменная, она указывает на расположение 
библиотеки SAP2000, методами которой Py и пользуется. Значение переменной такое, какое есть по факту. Причем у него тип string и оно заковычено, значит %20 стоять там не должно вместо пробелов и тогда вроде бы все нормально.

При запуске уже с ключом --console появляется вот такое...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое странное то, что он ссылается на временную папку, которой по указанному пути не существует и если запустить его повторно, то имя этой временной папки будет уже другое... Т.е. я так понимаю на начальном этапе, питти берет в temp распаковывает какие то файлы и в какой то момент опять хочет их использовать, но они в виду их временности уже удалены....

Как можно решить такую задачу с конвертацией в exe? Что я мог пропустить или делаю не так?.
PS:
CXFrezee (или как его там) тоже тестировал, результат такой же

Comment: ошибок несколько. Начните с `print("hello world")` (это полный код). Добейтесь что собранный exe   работает на машине без Питона¶ Для comtypes, вероятно необходимо включить (--hidden-import) автоматически сгенерированный модуль. См. пример для pywinauto: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3177#issuecomment-398360968 (в вашем случае имя модуля естественно другое)¶ Сообщения об ошибке следует как текст, а не снимки экрана добавлять.

Answer (score 2):

Про дополнительные ключи почитал, спасибо jfs и заработало. Для себя такого рода задачи решаю теперь так:

1. Компилирую в exe, но только `--onefile` я не использую, т.к. он работает в моем случае дольше, да и exe файлы по 50-60 мб немного пугают людей))))
2. Далее запускаем exe и потом в несколько итераций я дополнительно копирую модули, которых питу не хватает. В итоге получается папка типа FrameWork )))) пузырь внутри которого работает exe. Самое забавное то, что если понадобиться создать еще какой нить макрос новый, то после компиляции можно просто маленький exe из папки dist в эту папку "FrameWork" закинуть и уже и он работает полноценно используя всю сборку.
3. Далее я потом просто по сети ярлыки раскидываю пользователям на ехе-шники и они могут пользоваться, причем программа работает даже в ситуации, когда несколько человек одновременно exe запускают. Если код надо где-нибудь заменить, то опять просто exe заменил и юзеры не почувствовали на себе никаких последствий. Еще раз спасибо за помощь.